# NSFileSystemFileNumber is changed after file is edited/updated in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

I am working on **File Management System** exactly like ***Dropbox*** in *Cocoa*.

My problem is when i **edit** any text file at that time **NSFileSystemFileNumber** is changed.

I want an unique **NSFileSystemFileNumber** even if that edited file is moved from the particular folder.

In short, I just want to know how to fetch that moved file's old or original path from the database.

Any alternate way to solve out this problem?

Thanks in Adv..!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the editor save functionality is implemented.  Each editor will have different functionality and it sounds like the one you are using does the following:

1. Delete existing file.
2. Create new file.
3. Write file data.

Hence you get a new inode each time.  Others might:

1. Truncate existing file.
2. Write file data.

which would result in the same inode each time.

There is nothing you can about this so you will need to track file changes using the name or something, not the inode.

Comment: But if user rename that file in that case??

Comment: @jigs No idea, but I'm sure you will be told.

Comment: @jigs I cannot really comment on the design of your app as I don't know enough about it.

Comment: I just want to know how to fetch that moved file's old or original path from the database.

Comment: @jigs Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can use in your database.

Using `NSURL` API you can extract a great many attributes of your files. Some of which fit exactly your needs for identification.

Consult [NSURL documentation for the NSURLResourceKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlresourcekey?language=objc) set of constants.

Here's a code snippet.

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSArray *identifyingAttributes = @[NSURLFileResourceIdentifierKey, NSURLDocumentIdentifierKey, NSURLGenerationIdentifierKey];
NSDictionary<NSURLResourceKey, id> *fileAttributes = [fileURL resourceValuesForKeys:identifyingAttributes error:&error];
NSNumber *uniqueFileIdentifier = fileAttributes[NSURLDocumentIdentifierKey];
```

I think the [NSURLDocumentIdentifierKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurldocumentidentifierkey?language=objc) attribute is the one you're after, but maybe one of the others in the array may fit you better - read in the docs their very special behaviors.

Answer (score -2):

Just an Idea - something I haven't tried myself.

Why not use the old '**Alias**' mechanism of MacOS for that? create an Alias to the file/document/bundle/directory you want to track (to have a link to - despite it being moved or renamed, or its contents edited) - and save the **Alias** in your database. Then - you practically offload the problem (of tracking the file changes) to MacOS...

As far as I can remember (that's 20 years ago...) Aliases are objects - and not necessarily files - so you can save an alias anywhere. It's not like creating a symlink to the file you want to track - which creates yet another file-system object.

I need something similar, so I'll try this approach soon - If it works for me, I'll update here.