# NSDocument unique identifier

Tags: objective-c, macos, unique, uniqueidentifier, nsdocument

**Q:** Is there any way to acquire unique **identifier of NSDocument** in Document-based™ application which is persistent during app restarts?

*Note1: there definitely should be some kind of id which is not just [fileURL](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocument/1515038-fileurl?language=objc), but something else because app works well with autosaved and even not yet saved documents.*

*Note2: for some reasons I do not want to generate and persist this id to document's content file.*

Comment: Is your document a single file or a package?  Does it have a place to store metadata?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann it is a single plain-text file.

Comment: Related question: [NSFileSystemFileNumber is changed after file is edited/updated in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30187163/4244136)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving data into **coder** in a method 
[`encodeRestorableStateWithCoder`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocument/1526257-encoderestorablestatewithcoder?language=objc) during document closing and restoring that data in [`restoreDocumentWindowWithIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocument/1524586-restoredocumentwindowwithidentif?language=objc) when document is re-opened.

```
- (void) encodeRestorableStateWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder {
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder: coder];
    [coder encodeObject: @{@"color":@"red"} forKey: @"OBJECT_KEY"];
}

- (void) restoreDocumentWindowWithIdentifier: (NSString *) identifier
                                       state: (NSCoder *) state
                           completionHandler: (void (^) (NSWindow *, NSError *)) completionHandler {
    NSDictionary * restoredInfo = [state decodeObjectForKey: @"OBJECT_KEY"];
    [super restoreDocumentWindowWithIdentifier: identifier state: state completionHandler: completionHandler];
}
```

I think it is possible to save a generated UID there, but this storage might not be very reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Even I did not try it, I think that extended attributes can do the job:

```
uuid_t uuid;
[[NSUUID new] getUUIDBytes:uuid];

int result = setxattr( path, "com.yourcompany.yourapp.yourattr", &uuid, sizeof(uuid), 0, 0);
```

Since extended attributes are nor part of the file itself neither a standard to all file systems, they can be lost, when the file is copied on storage with a file system that does not support such attributes.